# Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $id ]] livewire

Tags: laravel, production-environment, laravel-livewire

This weird i am trying to send a id to the verify method it works locally and in production shows an error of Unable to resolve dependency.

Here is the code which trigger the event

```
<a wire:click='verifyComment({{$comment->id}})' class="px-4 py-2 text-white bg-indigo-600 rounded cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-900">Verify</a>
```

And the function

```
public function verifyComment($id)
    {
       $comment=Comments::find($id);
       $comment->verified=true;
       $comment->save();
       //updates the dashboard
       $this->getComments();
       $this->getTrendingPosts();

       session()->flash('message', 'Comment successfully verified.');
    }
```

I have tried so many using events but still can not make it work in production

Comment: make sure that all composer packages are installed ```composer install``` 
also make sure you have compiled all js files ``npm run:dev```

Comment: This really looks a dependency issue. Livewire uses an id behind the scene, so when you mount the component livewire doesn't find this id and the page brokes.
Is this happening when you click on the element or when the page is mounted?

Comment: @itepifanio So after so much hustle I found that in the production database the id was incorrectly named ID instead of id that's why locally was working but not in production.. Anyways thanks  very  much 

Comment: How do you solve? I got pretty much like that

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same issue. Turns out I was passing a string without ' '. So, I changed ```wire:click="removeItem({{ $cartItem->getHash() }})``` to ```wire:click="removeItem('{{ $cartItem->getHash() }}')```. Try this out might work for you too.